# angular first visit loading and not open page but next visited not loading, and open page why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to convert a template to angular that uses html, css, bootstrap, javascript and similar technologies.

The template has a loader function and a gif is placed on it.

When I visit it for the first time, it loads and does not open the page, but on the second and subsequent visits, it does not load and opens the page.

What should I do to make the page open when I first visit the page?
I don't understand, I think bootstrap's js files are not loaded, but how?

I put all the external files in assets and it's fine in the angular.json file too.

The problem I have is: for example, when I visit the index html page, everything works fine, but when I visit the about page, it doesn't work?

index.html page

[image]

about.html page first visit
[image]

about.html second visit used
[image]

What I don't understand is why it doesn't work on the first visit but it works on the 2nd visit?

I have tried many things.

You can also submit a pull request from the github repository.

https://github.com/muhammad-abdulloh/4UHOST

my index component and about component and angular json file

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tt9cmt?file=src/about.component.html

Comment: Angular is based in components. Angular have an unique index.html (the only has the ` <my-app>` tag. Then replace this tag with the different components acording the route you defined (so in components you have no html nor body nor head tags). I feel you should check the [tour of heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes) to understand a bit how Angular works

Comment: I Have one index html but I have index.component.html what is difference beeetweeen?

Comment: A component have code (in .ts) and (.html). You indicate the .html related to the component when define the [Component](https://angular.io/guide/component-overview). The important part is the "component.ts" that is a Class that you need import in a Module. I know that there're several concepts. Think a Component as a class that can see in a web (In pynthon was a component with tkinter)

Comment: I have adjusted all the settings you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

**I removed the loader part from the html file and it works great now :)**

Answer (score 0):

import style.scss and install bootstrap and add bootstrap (js and css) path in angular.json